# Flatten 3d Coordinates to 2d Coordinates

Tags: javascript, 3d, html5-canvas

I am trying to make some code that can take in 3d coordinates (x, y, z), and return 2d coordinates (x, y) by translating the x and y values towards the perspective point based on the z value.

My code is :

```
translate() {
            this.distance = Math.sqrt((this.x**2)+(this.y**2));
            this.bear = (180/Math.PI)*(Math.asin(this.y/this.distance));
            this.transX = (this.x + Math.cos(this.bear)*this.z);
            this.transY = (this.y + Math.sin(this.bear)*this.z);
        }
```

and gets me this:

[image: problem output]

To me, the code looks like it should just move the non-square points inwards but it doesn't.

Does anyone have any ideas to make this work? or are there other ways to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a perspective projection at it's simplest form, you don't have to do much. We simply determine a `scale` and apply the following calculation to all 3d coordinates:

```
projectedPoint = point * scale / (pointZ + scale)
```

Here's an example:

```js
class Point {
  constructor(x, y, z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
  }
}
let cube = [
  new Point(-50, -50, -50), new Point(50, -50, -50), new Point(50, 50, -50), new Point(-50, 50, -50),
  new Point(-50, -50, 50), new Point(50, -50, 50), new Point(50, 50, 50), new Point(-50, 50, 50)
];

function project(vertices) {
  let scale = 200;
  let projectedX, projectedY, x, y, z, point;
  let centerX = canvas.width / 2;
  let centerY = canvas.height / 2;
  for (let a = 0; a < vertices.length; a++) {
    point = vertices[a];
    ctx.beginPath();
    projectedX = centerX + point.x * scale / (point.z + scale);
    projectedY = centerY + point.y * scale / (point.z + scale);
    ctx.arc(projectedX, projectedY, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }

}
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
project(cube);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```